Kobweb API call to Firestore with error: "Address types of NameResolver 'unix' not supported by transport"
In kobweb project I have two modules: jsMain where I have frontend in kobweb.compose, and jvmMain where I have backend with API access point.
In jvmMain:
import com.varabyte.kobweb.api.Api

@Api(routeOverride = "getSettings")
fun getSettings(context: ApiContext) {
    val result = getCompanySettings()
    context.res.setBodyText(result)
}

fun getCompanySettings():String{
AppUtils.initializeFirebase()
    try {
        val future = com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient
            .getFirestore()
            .options.service
            .collection(AppConstants.FB_COMPANIES_COLLECTION)
            .document("test1")
            .get()

        val snapshot: DocumentSnapshot = future.get()

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            return snapshot.getString("settings").toString()

        } else {
            return "Snapshot not exists"
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return "Error: ${e.message}"
    }
}

If I test method getCompanySettings() (i.e. starting from main()), everything works fine and I receive data from Firestore. If I test @Api getSettings  in localhost with some String as response - also everything OK. I get the String in my WWW, but if try to get response from Firestore in my WWW, than I receive an error:

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address types of NameResolver 'unix' for 'firestore.googleapis.com:443' not supported by transport

How to solve it?
